# Убрать символы из строки php

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть строка такого формата

+77771112233

Как убрать +7 в среде Php, что бы получилось
7771112233

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('~^\+7~', '', $str);`

Comment: Много способов, если нужно убрать первые два символа — `substr("+77771112233", 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ещё один вариант

```
$str = str_replace('+7', '', '+77771112233');
```